# Why is this tap operator not firing?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm puzzled by this rxjs tap() operator never firing in this simple Angular component, while the Subject value does get updated on the screen. I also tried using a BehaviorSubject instead with the same results. What I'm I doing wrong here?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{ selectedUserId | async }}',
})
export class AppComponent { 

  selectedUserId = new Subject<number>();
  // selectedUserId = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedUserId
      .pipe(
        tap(id => console.log(id)) // why this is not logging to console?
      );
    setTimeout(() => this.selectedUserId.next(1), 1000);
    //this.selectedUserId.next(1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Try using a `BehaviorSubject`, so that it stores the last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the Observable the async pipe subscribes to doesn't have a tap.

Specifically, the pipe operator in

```
this.selectedUserId
  .pipe(
    tap(id => console.log(id)) // why this is not logging to console?
  );
```

doesn't modify the `Observable` stored in `this.selectedUserId`. Rather, it creates and returns a new `Observable` with the `tap`, but since you never `subscribe` to the returned Observable the `tap` is never called ...

Answer (score 1):

this line  `this.selectedUserId.pipe(tap(id => console.log(id)) );` return an new observable base of `selectedUserId` so you need to subscribe to new observable the start get the values and .

tab operater will work on the new observable and not effected the base observable (selectedUserId)

```
  const obs =  this.selectedUserId
      .pipe(
        tap(id => console.log(id)) 
      );

   obs.subscribe()
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7sqnf)

to make it clear the new observable will be run by async pipe , not that the values of observable will change base of the subject observable during the time

```
  private selectedUserId = new Subject<number>();
  public userId$ : Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.userId$ =  this.selectedUserId
      .pipe(
        tap(id => console.log(id)) ,
      );

    setTimeout(() => this.selectedUserId.next(1), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => this.selectedUserId.next(2), 2500);
    setTimeout(() => this.selectedUserId.next(3), 5000);
  }
```

template

```
{{ userId$ | async }}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zja2du)